# Spring: Autowire based on Constructor polymorphism

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have Component class Customer like:

```
class Customer{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Customer() {
        firstName = "dummy";
        lastName = "dummy";
    }

    public Customer(String first, String last) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }

}
```

I want to autowire Customer instance to below classes

```
class MainDefault{

    // Should autowire object with default Customer Constructor
    @Autowire
    private Customer customer;

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(customer.firstName);
    }

}

class Mainparameterized{

    // Should autowire object with parameterized Customer Constructor
    @Autowire
    private Customer customer;

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(customer.firstName);
    }
}
```

Here MainDefault should use the default constructor and the Mainparameterized should use the parameterized constructor.

What is the best way to do it.?

Comment: How would spring know parameter values to pass?

Comment: I don't know your purpose exactly. However, Spring Autowire annotation only used to inject bean to any class instance. If you want inject bean that is initialized via default or parameterized constructor, you should define one bean with default, second bean with parameter and inject specific bean that you want. For example: 
`<bean id="customer1" class="Customer"/>`
`<bean id="customer2" class="Customer">`
   `<constructor-arg name="first" value="Dany"/>`
     `<constructor-arg name="last" value="Lan"/>`
`</bean>`

Comment: @Prashant we can pass a constant value for the parameterized constructore

Comment: @NguaCon Agree, that's the trivial way to do it. But is there any other way which doesn't need to defines beans?

Comment: @pritamprasad, currently I think that has not any way. :)